# Unable to switch from JS to TS in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I changed the file extensions of my app files including app/app.js

`Error: Cannot find module 'app/app.js' from 'app_folder'`

It doesn't tell me which file I should be looking at to fix the error.

I tried looking with `git grep` and read a bit about Angular2's entry points to find out where it is loaded, but no luck yet.

Comment: the best way to switch from es5/es6 to typescript would be to start a new project and import all your files. $ ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2 --ts

Answer (score 3):

Using TypeScript into an Ionic2 project isn't just switching extensions of files ;-)

You need to integrate the TypeScript compiler into Gulp with the `gulp-tsc'` plugin:

```
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');

(...)

gulp.task('compile', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.src)
    .pipe(typescript({
      emitError: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js/'))
});
```

This page could help you:

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-typescript-example

Comment: I don't see those scripts anywhere in ionic 2. I looked in a new ionic project with and witouth `ts`. 

Also, the reason I thought it could be detected automatically without installing `gulp-tsc` is because even the when you build a ionic 2 project with `js`, the script inside the files is almost the same.

Comment: The code provided in my answer must take place in the `gulpfile.js` file. Yes almost the same ;-) since TypeScript is a superset of ES6 but there are some differences. This question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820243/angular-2-typscript-or-angular-2-javascript-which-one-is-advisable/36820376#36820376.

Answer (score 2):

Thierry Templier put me on the right track, and here is the answer.

Documentation in case anyone else is wondering.

Ionic2 is different than ionic1 basically uses browserify now. To switch from ES6 to TS, you would need to setup typscirpt for your project and set the dependencies like so:

1. in `gulpfile.js` change  `var buildBrowserify = require('ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015');`
    for `var buildBrowserify = require('ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript');`
2. in `package.json` change `ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015": "^1.0.2"`
   for `"ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^1.0.0"`
3. [Install typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings)

   3.1 `npm install typings --global`

   3.2 `tsd query node --action install --save`
4. Make sure you have the file `your_app/typings/main.d.ts`
   with the content: `/// <reference path="main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />`
5. lastly the `tsconfig.json` file

   `tsconfig{
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true
     },
     "filesGlob": [
       "**/*.ts",
       "!node_modules/**/*"
     ],
     "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "typings/main",
       "typings/main.d.ts"
     ],
     "compileOnSave": false,
     "atom": {
       "rewriteTsconfig": false
     }
   }`